# MAMP PRO - No Data Recived ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, mamp, mamp-pro

So I'm having an issue with a MAMP & Wordpress local install where frequently on reload I get a "No data received ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE" page. I also get the following in the console.

- /deep/ combinator is deprecated. See
  https://www.chromestatus.com/features/6750456638341120 for more
  details. http://localhost:8888/xxx/:1 GET
- http://localhost:8888/xxx/ net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
- http://localhost:8888/xxx/:1 GET http://localhost:8888/xxx/
  net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

I've not been able to find anything that addresses these errors, except to restart the server. Not sure what else I need to do to trouble shoot this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been getting this error constantly over the past few days. I found that if I switched themes back to the default **twentyfifteen** it solved the issue.

There was obviously an error somewhere in my custom theme, so I started to re-name files to find the culprit. It ended up being the **functions.php** file. There was this snippet of code in there:

```
'packages-nav' => _('Packages Nav'),
```

The single underscore was causing the issue.

Try a similar method on your theme to find the error. Not sure if this is any help, but I've been Googling the issue and couldn't find any solutions, so when I found a fix I wanted to share.

Comment: Did ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE happen each time you made a request or just sometimes? I have the same issue, but it only happens here and now, not always. And only when accessing certain AJAX stuff..